# A question on the proof of Bedford-Taylor theorem in Demailly's book

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, potential-theory, several-complex-variables

I am trying to understand a proof of the Bedford-Taylor theorem on the weak convergence of Monge-Ampere operators of decreasing sequences of plurisubharmonic functions.

I am reading a proof in  the book by J.-P. Demailly "[Complex analytic and differential geometry](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf)".
This is Theorem 3.7 in Ch. III. On p. 149, lines 3-4 one uses integration by parts
$$\int_\Omega u_1^{k,\varepsilon_1}dd^cu_2\wedge\dots dd^cu_q\wedge T\wedge \beta^m=
\int_\Omega u_2 dd^cu_1^{k,\varepsilon_1}\wedge\dots dd^cu_q\wedge T\wedge \beta^m,$$
where $T$ is a closed positive current, $\beta$ is a Kaehler form. It is claimed that there is no boundary term since the functions $u_1^{k,\varepsilon_1}, u_2$ vanish on the boundary
(note that in a neighborhood of the boundary these functions are also smooth).

**I still not understand why this integration by parts is possible since the positive current $T$ may not be smooth near the boundary.**

Comment: Do you really need it to be smooth? I mean we can itegrate any form that is just in $L^1(\Omega)$ for example and also use integration by parts when the integrands terms are in some Sobolev space.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain : smoothness is sufficient for the purposes of the proof. May be a stronger statement is true.